# Adding custom anchor links and page links in WordPress menu clash

Tags: wordpress

I've created two pages, one to act as a onepage site and one for the blog. 
I have anchor links on sections on my onepage  to 'about', 'portfolio' etc. for the onepage. I have a page link to 'blog'.

On my menu I have created custom links to each section as #about and #portfolio and this works fine. However, if I go into the Blog and try to use the menu to go back to a section on the onepage it doesn't work as I get www.example.com/blog#about

But if I set the anchor links in the menu to http://example.com#about, http://example.com#portfolio etc then *none* of the anchor links work. I'm stuck. Would love some help please

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:
Easier than I thought. The onepage was named 'home' so all I needed to do was create custom links like: http://www.example.com/home#portfolio