# Conditionally rewrite links to anchors according to actual page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Similar to [Adding custom anchor links and page links in WordPress menu clash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36571989/adding-custom-anchor-links-and-page-links-in-wordpress-menu-clash)
 but not quite the same.

I'm working on a wordpress website with a main menu containing links to anchors to several homepage sections (example.com/index.php#anchor1, example.com/index.php#anchor2, etc) and links to sections (example.com/contact). I have permalinks activated (/%postname%/).

While on homepage, all works great: The anchor links do the scroll animation and the sections links works. But from a sections the anchor links don't work, just point to "example.com/contact#anchor1". Modifiyng in any way the links (with "/" or "index.php") either doesn't load on anchor from sections or reload the page when on homepage, instead of scrolling to the desired anchor.

The solution user2840467 use on the aforementioned question doesn't help since i'm using a custom post home page.

So: How could be done, with javascript or jquery, a conditional rule to rewrite the main menu anchor links only on sections? So, for example, an anchor link on the menu would be `<a href="#anchor1">Some anchor</a>`, but while on "example.com/contact" it gets rewritten to `<a href="example.com/#anchor1">Some anchor</a>`.

Additional info:

This is my menu:

```
<ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
 <li><a href="#builder1">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#tm-main">Find a sale</a></li>
 <li><a href="#widget-text-63">How it works</a></li>
 <li><a href="#widget-text-61">Sign in</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://example.com/my-sales/">My sales</a></li>
 <li><a href="https://example.com/faq/">FAQ</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You want a solution in javasript ?

Comment: Please provide some relevant HTML from the page so we can see the ids or names of the divs and other elements of a representative example.

Comment: @jwpfox there I specified the menu i'm using. All the anchors are on homepage, and work fine only while there

Comment: Is the menu you are showing us the same on every page?

Comment: @jwpfox yes, the same all across the site

Answer (score 1):

You can get url in javasript so here is how you can do it with jQuery.

```
var current_url = window.location.href;
var hostname = window.location.origin;

  //compare two url to check if you are at homepage
  if(current_url != hostname){

    //for each a you need to change the href attribute
    //you should change .menu to your class or id so you will change only a elements inside your menu
    $('.menu a').each(function(){
      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      $(this).attr('href',hostname+'#'+href);
    });
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, I have been trying to implement your solution but I can't get to make it work. I'm not good on javascript, sorry. I've changed '.menu' to my class, but haven't figured out how to apply the href attribute change. For example, one of the links is #tm-main.

Comment: On firefox inspector show an error: "TypeError: $ is not a function", in reference to  **$** ('.menu a').each(function(){

Comment: I suspect you haven't included jQuery on the page. If you don't know how to include jQuery on a page read this: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: @renato you should include jQuery on the page or if you have included it you need to make sure that this script is running after your included jQuery file. And in my solution you don't have to do nothing because it replaces href attributes dynamically

Comment: @edisoni.1337 Ok, I managed make it work. I checked jquery as both suggested, and was already loaded by wordpress. So as suggested on another question at this website, I added the DOM ready function **jQuery(function($) {** and the script rewrite the links (i've just changed **$(this).attr('href',hostname+'#'+href);** to **$(this).attr('href',hostname+'/'+href);** since the hashtag was already on the link, but the slash not). But despite the fact that links are being rewritten properly (checked on inspector) when clicked still point to the same page, like no changes were made.

Comment: @edisoni.1337 thanks for your help by the way. I think your answer is the right one, but at the moment, while I'm on the right path, I haven't managed to solve this last problem, were the links are modified, but respond as nothing had changed. Hope your answer. Regards

Comment: So you are at homepage and the links are fine but when u go to a specific page links are not ok ? Can you give me an example how it looks in inspect elements and where it redirects you

Comment: @edisoni.1337 Thanks for your answer. So, for example: A link is setup on wordpress as `#builder1`, with the script it gets rewritten and I know it because on inspector it looks like `https://example.cl/#builder1` (wich is good), but you click it and works as if it would be `#builder1`, as if the script weren't there. Also, I realized trough inspector that the script change the links on homepage too, like `if(current_url != hostname)` line wouldn't working, so the same behaviour repeates throughout the whole site, regardless of whether you are on the home page or not

Comment: @renato did you fixed it ?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like something you should do with Javascript, but rather server-side, but this should work:

Just add the class 'cond-link' to those links or change the jQuery selector. Also: [Here is a working CodePen](https://codepen.io/SourceOverflow/pen/qPqdwO).

(Note that CodePen uses a iFrame and therefore the link is different to that of the pen, therefore I had to manually set it)

```
var thisLink = window.location.pathname;
$('.cond-link').each(function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  if(href.match("^" + thisLink)) {
    var newHref = href.split('#')[1]
    $(this).attr('href', href.replace(thisLink, ''));
  }
});
```